# Adding drupal node containing date in drupal-ios-sdk

Tags: ios, drupal

I am developing an iOS app that needs to create drupal nodes.  I am using drupal-ios-sdk to create the nodes.  It works fine sending strings to text fields in drupal but the node also needs to contain a date field.  When I convert and format the NSDate to a string and put it in a dictionary and send like a text field I get an error from the drupal services module indicating that the date is in the wrong format.  What is the correct format or where would I find some documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best way to find it.
Create a node on your Drupal site first and check the database column for your date field. Then send the date value in the date value in the same format. Also, if you are using date module -- that's obvious, you can convert the string using some date function from the date module.

Comment: Thanks. The person who set up the Drupal node said that date is in YYYYMMDDHHMMSS format. He said to separate by commas.  I sent

Comment: I sent string 2013,07,31,09,45,09 and got error containing: `code`{NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion={"form_errors":{"field_s4_date][und][0":"Th‌​ere are errors in S4_Date value #1:<div class=\"item-list\"><ul><li class=\"first last\">The dates are invalid.</li>\n</ul></div>"}}  `code`

Comment: It does not matter in what format you sent the data, just use the date functions to convert in respective format at Drupal end!

Comment: Thanks, maybe I am not understanding.  It does not add the node because the format is wrong so there is nothing to convert at the Drupal end.  Should I send into a text field rather than a date field so that the date can be converted?

Comment: By converting to respective format I mean, before you save the node! You completely missed the point!

Comment: Consider this:
$ss__date = format_date($om__result->date, 'custom', 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
$node->field_date = array(
  0 => array(
    'value' => $ss__date, 
  ),
);

Does this make sense?